# Java path variable. Nothing is fixing it at all

Tags: java, path, environment-variables

I have been trying to fix my Java path variable. I keep getting "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". Is there any convenient software that fixes the path settings automatically?

Currently Path Variable is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;PATH;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"

What do I do I have no clue? This is very frustrating. Please help.

Comment: Do you have the full JDK installed or just the JRE?  I would expect the path to your `javac` binary to include `jdk1.8.0_101` as opposed to `jre1.8.0_101` like you currently have.

Comment: If that's your whole path, then it looks like to rooked it pretty severely.

Answer (score 0):

javac require you to have JDK installed instead of JRE.
If you have already installed JDK, try changing JAVA_HOME variable to your JDK root directory (eg: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101")